# 401 unauthorized access in webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a program that creates a screenshot of the site using winform and webbrowser.
I get an error 401 unauthorized access in the string below:
WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();

How to launch URL with successful authorization?

```
namespace WebBrowserScreenshotSample
{
   class Program
   {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
           int width = 800;
           int height = 1200;

            NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("login@domain", "password");

            WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("URL");
            myCredentials.Domain = "domain";
            myWebRequest.Credentials = myCredentials;

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nCredentials Domain : {0}, UserName : {1}, Password : {2}", myCredentials.Domain, myCredentials.UserName, myCredentials.Password);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nRequest to Url is sent.Waiting for response...");

            WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse received successfully.");

            using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
            {
                browser.Width = width;
                browser.Height = height;
                browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
                browser.DocumentCompleted += Program.OnDocumentCompleted;
                browser.Navigate("URL");
                Application.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try comparing the response of a 'real' visit vs the programmed one. Are you setting the user-agent value? a lot of websites don't like a request without one.

Comment: This mix of `WebRequest` and `WebBrowser` won't ever go anywhere. Are you trying to Login to a WebSite which has a WebForm to fill in with credentials? Use just the `WebBrowser` (possibly on a Form, since you want a screenshot of a Web page), using its `HtmlDocument` tools to perform the Login. Note that `NetworkCredential` are only used in Basic/Digest Authentication.